# Is there a way to have 2 different y axis with completely different scale (no link at all)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to have 2 y-axes, 1 for Average Price (Price), 1 for Count. Both the line and bar will be in the same plot. Is there any way?

```
ggplot()+
geom_line(data=test,aes(x=year,y=price),group=1)+
geom_bar(data=test1,aes(x=year,y=count,fill=sale),stat="Identity")
```

The finished result will be something like the [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkRez.png) attached.

```
scale_y_continuous(name="price",
                   sec.axis = sec_axis(~./a, name = "count"))
```

I tried this code, but i am not sure what to put at ***~./a*** because the y-axes are not linked, so i cannot do a division or addition.

I would like to do it as a plotly if possible. Thanks!

Comment: I guess this is not possible. From `?sec_axis` : _All secondary axes must be based on a one-to-one transformation of the primary axes_

Comment: Regarding the use of a secondary axis you might want to read [Stephen Few's discussion on the topic](http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/dual-scaled_axes.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:8),
                 y1 = c(1100, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700), 
                 y = c(140, 120, 100, 80, 60, 40, 20, 0)) 

ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(y = y, x = x), data = df) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = (y1 -1000)/5, x = x), stat = "identity", data = df) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.*5+1000)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>